# tellg() in cpp : unexpected output

Tags: c++

I don't seem to understand why tellg() in this cpp program returning value -1. Here's the program

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{

char a[20];
long t;

ofstream of;
ifstream in;

in.open("s.txt");

of.open("d.txt");

in.getline(a,20);                                   //reading from s.txt
of << a;                                            //writing into d.txt
cout << "\nThe Data in file D is - " << a << endl;

in.close();
of.close();

in.open("d.txt");

in.seekg(2,ios::beg);

in.getline(a,5);
cout << "After Moving 2 spaces - " << a <<endl;

t = in.tellg();
cout<<"TellG() : " << t <<endl;


in.close();

return 0;
}
```

And the file "s.txt" contain the following in manner as it is -

*abcdefghij

klmnopqrst

uvwxyz*

I think the expected output should be 7.

The output of the following program that I'm getting is

The Data in file D is - abcdefghij
After moving 2 spaces - cdef
TellG() : -1

Comment: You open `d.txt`, which does not contain anything. the output `-1` means that the search went to the end of the file without finding anything

Comment: but I copied content from s.txt to d.txt

Comment: @meetaig: What "search"? If you mean EOF, no that's not what `tellg() == -1` means. Read documentation. http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/tellg

Comment: Sorry I misread the code. I thought you were using seek not tell... Tell obviously does not perform a search. I can imagine that `tellg` returns -1 because you read a line and the cursor is set to the next line after that. But that is just guessing